# Chaining angular $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, promise

I'm trying to chain calls to AngularJS's `$timeout` function. I've seen lots of threads on here which allow the chaining of promises, some specifically using angular's `$q`, but this seems like it should be super simple. I guess I'm missing something obvious. Here's what I'd *like* to do:

```
$timeout(firstFunction, firstDelay)
.then($timeout(secondFunction, secondDelay))
.then($timeout(thirdFunction, thirdDelay));
```

While all three functions get called, the `$timeout`s all start simultaneously. I can see why this doesn't work, but *how* do I get what I want? Can I even use promises here? I was previously just arranging the delays so that they cascade, but that seems like more work to maintain...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `$timeout`s are executing immediately. Wrap them in functions that will be called when each promise resolves...

```
$timeout(firstFunction, firstDelay)
    .then(function () { return $timeout(secondFunction, secondDelay); })
    .then(function () { return $timeout(thirdFunction, thirdDelay); });
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing, the `then`s all get called at the same time. The inner functions must _return_ `$timeout(...)`.

Comment: Yes, chaining promises should have to be **returned**.